# Create Coupon/Price rule for first 10 Customers .(Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, coupon, price-rules

I want to create a price rule in magento 2, and want that to be active only for the first 10 Customers . Is it possible to achieve that ?
Thank You !

Comment: Mr.Yigen my answer will helpfull for you

Answer (score 2):

1. If your price rule doesn't require a coupon code, there's no way to limit it to only be used by the first 10 customers without creating an observer and custom code
2. If your price rule requires a coupon code, then you can set the value of **Uses per Coupon** to **10**. This will restrict the coupon and after it was used 10 times it will no longer be valid.
3. This will not prevent the **same** customer from using the coupon code twice. If you want to restrict the coupon use to only once per customer, set the value of **Uses per Customer** to **1**
4. Even if you restrict **Uses per Customer**, it will only apply to logged-in customers. Meaning that a non logged-in customer will still be able to use the coupon code twice.

Attached is a screenshot for your reference.[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Cart Price Rule** have option to create how many users going to use coupon?

Below I attached screenshots for your reference

[image]

**User per customer is 10** - only 10 user/customer will use your coupon